# Javax Pattern annotation failing for correct values

Tags: java, regex, spring, rest

I need to use validation where input value should end with "Type" So I came up with *Type$* regex, but it is failing for correct values. Here is how I am using this in Pattern annotation in my code

```
@Pattern(regexp = REGISTRY_CONFIG_TYPE_FORMAT,message = REGISTRY_CONFIG_TYPE_ERROR)
@ApiModelProperty(name = "registryConfigType", dataType = "String", value = "OccasionType", example = "OccasionType", required = true)
private String registryConfigType;
```

the constant value

```
REGISTRY_CONFIG_TYPE_FORMAT = "Type$"
```

when I am passing value like : OccasionType, I am getting the error message. But on regex101 it's working fine. Not sure where is the problem.

[image]

following is the error log which I am getting

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public com.macys.registry.dataobject.v1.response.RegistryAppResponse<java.lang.Object> com.macys.registry.controller.RegistryConfigController.updateConfig(com.macys.registry.dataobject.v1.request.UpdateRegistryConfigRequest): [Field error in object 'updateRegistryConfigRequest' on field 'registryConfigType': rejected value [OccasionType]; codes [Pattern.updateRegistryConfigRequest.registryConfigType,Pattern.registryConfigType,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [updateRegistryConfigRequest.registryConfigType,registryConfigType]; arguments []; default message [registryConfigType],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@20999237,Type$]; default message [Registry Config Type Should Not Be Null And Should End With [Type]]] ]
```

Comment: On the left side of Regex101, you've selected `PCRE2` instead of `Java 8`

Comment: same output for java

Comment: Could you share the error.

Comment: @divine_rythm you're right, my bad :)

Comment: @Sumit - I am getting custom error which I have passed in pattern annotation : message = REGISTRY_CONFIG_TYPE_ERROR

Comment: Have you tried without Constant variable like "Type$"

Comment: @Janil101 - yes same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be 100% clear from the javadoc, but the `regexp` must *match*. In other words, the entire input must be captured by the `regexp`. A simple fix: `.*Type`. Note that the `$` is unnecessary, as that's already implied by the matching.

Your regex would be valid if *find* where used instead of *match*.

Comment: he need $ as he wants the word to end with Type.

Comment: @xMilos you get that for free when using regex *match* instead of *find* - the entire input must be used.

Answer (score 4):

Try this for your case

```
REGISTRY_CONFIG_TYPE_FORMAT= ".*Type$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you constant to:

```
REGISTRY_CONFIG_TYPE_FORMAT = "\\w*Type\\b";
```

From [RegExr](https://regexr.com/):

```
\w  Word. Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
  *  Quantifier. Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
T  Character. Matches a "T" character (char code 84). Case sensitive.
y  Character. Matches a "y" character (char code 84). Case sensitive.
p  Character. Matches a "p" character (char code 84). Case sensitive.
e  Character. Matches a "e" character (char code 84). Case sensitive.
\b  Word boundary. Matches a word boundary position between a word character and non-word character or position (start / end of string).
```

Hope this will help.